# Not able to connect to redis which is in diffrent system with in docker and spring boot server running on different system in docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, redis

Getting Exception java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused when i'm trying to connect to  redis server.

this is to redis property which i have mentioned to connect

`spring.redis.database=2
spring.redis.host=172.15.5.100`

//this is my system ip address where redis container is running

`` spring.redis.port=6380
`spring.redis.sentinel.master= redis ``

This is my docker-compose-yml file

```
services:
    server:
      container_name: server
      build: .
      ports: 
          - "8080:8080"
          - "3000:3000"
      depends_on:
          - redis_presence_system

    redis_presence_system:
      container_name: redis
      image: "redis:4.0.9" 
      hostname: redis
      ports:
        - "6380:6380"
      expose:
        - "6380"
      volumes:
         - ./redis-data:/data    
      restart: always``


Error message which i'm getting
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207) [jedis-2.9.0.jar:] at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93) [jedis-2.9.0.jar:] at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767) [jedis-2.9.0.jar:] at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106) [jedis-2.9.0.jar:] at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:888) [commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3] at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:432) [commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3] at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361) [commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3] at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49) [jedis-2.9.0.jar:] ... 27 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80] at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80] at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80] at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second number in `ports:` needs to match the port the process inside the container is listening on.  This is usually the "normal" port for the service you're running; in the case of Redis, port 6379.  So change

```
ports:
  - "6380:6379"
```

(You don't need to set `container_name:`, `hostname:`, or `expose:`; these don't actually set any properties that are relevant to most applications, and there are reasonable defaults for all of them.)

When you’re connecting between two containers you need to configure it using the internal hostname (the name of the `services:` block) and the port number the process itself is listening on.  `ports:` have no effect, and aren’t actually necessary just to connect between containers.  In your application you also need to set

```
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.sentinel.master=redis_presence_system
```

matching the standard Redis port number, and the name of the Redis service block in the Compose YAML file.

Comment: @DaviMaze, i tried your approach  it's showing same error.

Comment: Sorry, I addressed the wrong issue.  I’ve edited the question to also discuss inter-container communication.

Comment: ``spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.sentinel.master=redis_presence_system``This properties i should metioned to the another system where i need to connect to redis.